# Read unix log for message and then perform action

Tags: bash, grep, tail

I am looking to create a shell script to read the message log and when finds the correct string perform an action. So far I have the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
string="ntp engine ready"
tail -n 0 -f /var/log/messages | \
while read LINE
do
echo "$LINE | grep -q $string"
if [ $? == 0];then
shttpclient "http://127.0.0.1/do/action"
fi
done
```

But, I get the following error:

```
grep: engine: No such file or directory
grep: ready: No such file or directory
```

Even when I see the logger has outputted `ntp engine ready`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you need to fix your quotes:

```
echo "$LINE" | grep -q "$string"
```

Secondly, you can simply do:

```
if echo "$LINE" | grep -q "$string"; then
```

rather than checking the return code `$?` manually. Remember that `[` is a command too and `if` is just checking its return code.

If you do need to use `[`, remember that `]` is an argument to the command so it is essential to surround it with spaces:

```
if [ $? = 0 ]
```

I have also removed the second `=` as it is a bash extension to support it. Actually you are doing an integer comparison, so really it should be one of the following:

```
if [ $? -eq 0 ]  # POSIX compliant
if (( $? == 0 )) # bash arithmetic context
```

Comment: thanks like i said a bit of a newbie even to this form, thank you for all the help

Comment: @Erik no problem, thanks for accepting my answer. I would recommend taking the [tour] if you haven't already done so, it doesn't take long and contains information about this kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

Alter the line as follows:

```
echo "$LINE" | grep -q "$string"
```

The quotes were not set correctly. Like when you execute that: `grep -q ntp engine ready`; `ntp` is the string to search and `engine` and `ready` are the files. It must look like: `grep -q "ntp engine ready"`.